# Azure pipeline run build on Pull Request branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to run a pipeline with changes from the Feature branch with the stable branch?

1) I have 2 branches that called  `develop` and `feature`.

2) I'm trying to do a Pull Request between the `develop` branch and `feature` branch.

3) I've configured under the develop branch policy to run a successful pipeline.
Used the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation)

4) When we will run a Pull Request will it merge and run the pipeline on the `develop` branch with the `feature` branch changes or only on the `develop` branch?

---

Frankly my question is when launching the PR its processing the new changes from the child branch with the source branch and running the pipeline on the source branch ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PR will run on its own branch `refs/pull/{pullId}/merge`.

A simple place this can be seen is looking at the checkout task of the build you've setup for your policy.

[image]

Depending on some of your configuration options (merging strategy and such), the merge branch should contain the prospective results of merging `feature` into `develop`.

I believe the policy mechanism would cut a branch from the target and merge the source in.